# Azure Pipeline Publish Files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a situation that's driving me crazy.

So I have this application that uses MEF and I have several class library projects, that each one of them it's a MEF plugin.

Some of them have dependencies, this dependences are plugin specific, so they exist only in the plugin output folder. One example it's the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and when I build the project I'll get some dlls in the output folder and a new folder runtimes, with the several versions that are target specific for the library.

Since this is a plugin, the system cannot infer the correct version of the assemblies that it needs to load at runtime. So I added a postbuild script, that copies from the specific subfolder to the root the ones that it needs to run, in this example it replaces 6 files and add a new one.

This works fine locally, the problem it's on Azure running the dotnet publish command...

I can see that it runs the postbuild, and copy the files that I expected to be copied to the build directory, but when it "moves" the result from the build folder to the output directory specified in the dotnet publish, it just passes the original output, ignoring completely the ones that I copied before.

So how can I have the copied files in the publish folder?

I already tried the other way around, using the posbuild script to copy the files directly to the publish directory, but when it publishes, it replaces the files that I just copied, just leaving the one that is new...